# Join two files by matching a specific column

Tags: linux, join, awk, sed

I'm trying to join two files which are already sorted

File1

```
70 CBLB Cbl proto-oncogene B
70 HOXC11 centrosomal protein 57
70 CHD4 chromodomain helicase
70 FANCF FA complementation
70 LUZP2 leucine zipper protein 2
```

File2

```
0.700140820757797 ELAVL1
0.700229616476825 HOXC11
0.700328646327188 CHD4
0.700328951649384 LUZP2
```

Output

```
Gene Symbol  Gene Description         Target Score mirDB   Target Score Diana
HOXC11       centrosomal protein 57   70                   0.700229616476825
CHD4         chromodomain helicase    70                   0.700328646327188
LUZP2        leucine zipper protein 2 70                   0.700328951649384
```

To perform this task, I have tried with this script, but it returns an empty file

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.4 File1 File2 | column -t | sed '1i Gene Symbol, Gene 
Description, Target Score mirDB, Target Score Diana' > Output
```

Any help with awk or join commands requested.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** updated `awk` to remove Windows line endings (`\r`) as this popped up as an issue during comments/other-question with OP

---

Issues:

- OP's current code needs to pre-sort both files before calling `join`
- due to the variable number of white space delimited columns in `File1` it's going to be hard (impossible?) to get `join` to generate a format that won't be scrambled by the follow-on `column` call
- `column` cannot distinguish between spaces used as field delimiters vs spaces as part of a field

Due to these issues I think an `awk` solution, combined with `column` for an 'easy' reformat, is easier to implement and understand, eg:

```
awk '
BEGIN      { OFS="|"                              # "|" will be used as the input delimiter for a follow-on "column" call
             print "Gene Symbol", "Gene Description", "Target Score mirDB", "Target Score Diana"
           }
           { sub(/\r/,"") }                       # remove Windows line ending "\r" for all lines in all files
FNR==NR    { gene[$2]=$1 ; next }
$2 in gene { lastF=pfx=""
             for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {                # pull fields #3 to #NF into a single variable 
                 lastF=lastF pfx $i
                 pfx=" "
             }
             print $2, lastF, $1, gene[$2]
           }
' File2 File1
```

This generates:

```
Gene Symbol|Gene Description|Target Score mirDB|Target Score Diana
HOXC11|centrosomal protein 57|70|0.700229616476825
CHD4|chromodomain helicase|70|0.700328646327188
LUZP2|leucine zipper protein 2|70|0.700328951649384
```

While it is possible to add some more code so that `awk` prints the output in 'pretty' columns, I've opted for a simpler approach of letting `column` do the extra work:

```
awk '
BEGIN      { OFS="|" 
             print "Gene Symbol", "Gene Description", "Target Score mirDB", "Target Score Diana"
           }
           { sub(/\r/,"") }                       # remove Windows line ending "\r" for all lines in all files
FNR==NR    { gene[$2]=$1 ; next }
$2 in gene { lastF=pfx=""
             for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {
                 lastF=lastF pfx $i
                 pfx=" "
             }
             print $2, lastF, $1, gene[$2]
           }
' File2 File1 | column -s'|' -t
```

This generates:

```
Gene Symbol  Gene Description          Target Score mirDB  Target Score Diana
HOXC11       centrosomal protein 57    70                  0.700229616476825
CHD4         chromodomain helicase     70                  0.700328646327188
LUZP2        leucine zipper protein 2  70                  0.700328951649384
```

Comment: It is a very good solution. I wonder if it is possible to make the comma separations `(;) or (,)` to output a csv format. As there are longer gene descriptions the values are mixed up.

Comment: if I understand your question: **1)** set `OFS=';'` or `OFS=','` (or whatever you decide) and **2)** do not pipe to `column` (ie, remove the `| column -s'|' -t`); if that doesn't answer your question I'd suggest creating a new question with the necessary details ...

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I just get the header `Gene Symbol;Gene Description;Target Score mirDB;Target Score Diana`

Comment: just changing to `OFS=";"` I still get the same 4 output lines as shown above; are you feeding the same 2 files (`File2` and `File1`) to `awk`?

Comment: I really appreciate your support. I'm just fixing the formatting. I have the only issue at the end `Gene Description` values, there is a line break and the `;` is written the next line. `Gene Symbol;Gene Description;Target Score mirDB;Target Score Diana
NPTX1;neuronal pentraxin 1
;100;0.999551316662558
FGD4;FYVE, RhoGEF and PH domain containing 4
;70;0.768034158332055`

Comment: if you're using `printf` make sure you end each line with `\n`, otherwise I don't see how anything in my answer's going to cause what you're describing; I suggest you open a new question to address the new issue; also, if your input file is coming from a Windows environment make sure you remove the Windows line endings (`\r`) as those can cause some funky issues with input parsing and/or output printing; `dos2unix` is good for removing `\r`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "Gene Symbol", "Gene Description", "Target Score mirDB", "Target Score Diana"} NR==FNR{array[$2]=$1; next} $0!~array[$2]{print $2,OFS $3" "$4" "$5,$6, $1,OFS array[$2]}' file2 file1

Gene Symbol     Gene Description        Target Score mirDB      Target Score Diana
HOX11           centrosomal protein 57          70              0.700229616476825
CHD4            chromodomain helicase           70              0.700328646327188
LUZP2           leucine zipper protein  2       70              0.700328951649384
```

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t" 
    print "Gene Symbol", "Gene Description", "Target Score mirDB", "Target Score Diana"
} NR==FNR {
    array[$2]=$1
    next
} $0!~array[$2] {
    print $2,OFS $3" "$4" "$5,$6, $1,OFS array[$2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, join and column):

```
( echo 'Gene Symbol@Gene Description@Target Score mirDB@Target Score Diana';
join -j2 -t@ --no -o 0,1.3,1.1,2.1 <(sed 's/ /@/;s//@/' file1) <(sed 's/ /@/' file2) ) |
column -s@ -t
```

Formulate the final headings, join the two input files and pass the total output to the column command that tabulates the result.

N.B. The headings are delimited by the `@` an arbitrary character not found in the headings or joined files. The input files are amended so that their field delimiters match those of the headings and the column command uses the same delimiter to tabulate the final result. The `--no` (short for `--nocheck-order`) prevents warning messages.